# comparing select option value

Tags: jquery

By using the following code I am able to get the matched items. How to find the unmatched items from this:

```
$('#list1 option').each(function (i, option)                        
    $('#list2 option').each(function (j, option) {
       if ($('#list1 option').val() ==$('#list2 option').val())
           matchedList= $('#list1 option').val()
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of the `each` loop callback holds a reference to the HTML element, `HTMLOptionElement`, in this case. Simply use the `value` property to compare the values.

Use a `!==` to negate the comparison.

```
var nonMatchedList = [];
$('#list1 option').each(function (i, option1) {
    $('#list2 option').each(function (j, option2) {
       if (option1.value !== option2.value) {
           nonMatchedList.push(option1.value);  // Add to list
           return false;                        // Stop looping through list2
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its not working properly. output contains multiple times of list1 items

Comment: @user930453 Updated answer to not show an `<option>` more than once.